# Why are headphone wires so thin?

Tags: wire

Speaker wire is thick so why are the wires that go from a stereo plug to earbuds so thin? They seem unnecessarily thin. Is this so they break easier and then I need to buy another pair of headphones?

Answer (score 4):

Headphone wires are so thin, because the power transmitted is low, and there are technical and economic reasons to keep the wires thin.

Proper speakers use large amounts of power to drive the magnetics inside them, to get a good decibel (sound power) output.

Little earbuds go straight into your ear canal, the transmission power can be extremely low in comparison, and it's very directional. The tiny little speakers in those need such low power, that thin wires is fine to transmit on.

Remember the more current you need through a conductor, the larger it should be to avoid losses due to good old Ohm's law (voltage dropped through a resistive conductor, due to current). As sweber mentions in the comments, the length of the wire plays a part in how thick the wires need to be - if the cable is long, like in a speaker system, the resistance needs to be kept low over the distance, and thicker wires (cross sectional area for a conductor) help with this. Since earbud cables are quite short, usually about a metre long, and for the expected current draw, thin wires are acceptable.

Finally, there is an economic benefit to not over-sizing the conductor for earbuds. Copper is expensive, especially if you are manufacturing millions of units of something, there can be a huge difference in price between one gauge wire and another, from the weight of copper involved. If you can technically transmit on a thin wire, and it's economic to do so, then why not? They are usually stranded wires to help with flexibility and reduce metal fatigue, and the wires are almost always coated with protective plastics or fabrics to reduce stress on the wires. The rubberized insulating around the wires is to avoid axial and shear stress from breaking the wires.

So no, it's not a conspiracy to make you buy more crap.

Comment: Also note that speaker cables usually are much much longer that headphone cables. To maintain the resistance for a longer cable, the cross section has to be increased.

Comment: @sweber: Wait, people are not usually running around their apartment with 15m of headphone cable so they can listen everywhere?

Comment: I once had a 5m extension cord for my headphones. While not sufficient for the whole apartment, it was OK for the room. Today, it's somewhat... _outdated_ :-) . To be serious, I just wanted to mention that a 15m cable needs 10x the cross section compared to 1.5m, just to maintain the resistance. And as you need more power for speakers, you end up with this rope like cables...

Comment: This explains why they don't have to be thick, not why they are thin.

Comment: @PeteBecker "The tiny little speakers in those need such low power, that thin wires is okay to transmit on." Also, the fact that copper is costly so if you producing millions of headphones/earphones it pays to reduce wire gauge

Comment: The question is "why are the wires so thin", not "how can they make them so thin". All the talk about power, resistance, size, length, etc. goes to the latter. None of it answers the actual question. "Copper is costly" is the beginning of an answer.

Comment: @PeteBecker would you prefer me to update my answer, or would you like to add one? I don't mind either way, i'm all for a better quality EE.SE

Comment: I think your answer just needs an opening sentence with something like (although a bit more detailed) "It's cheaper because you don't need as much stuff, and you can do that because...".

Answer (score 2):

They're made to be cheap, light, unobtrusive and flexible. I don't think it's a conspiracy to make you buy more, but there's only so much that can be done with a small amount of affordable material. Less material means less volume and weight (so less shipping cost, since you can pack more into a TEU shipping container), as well as less material cost.

More professional over-the-ear headphones often have heavy wires that will stand up to a lot of abuse, and can be replaced when they fail. For example, [this one](http://www.akg.com/pro/k812-professional-headphones) which uses a [Lemo connector on the headphone end](http://media.bestquestions.com/bestquestions/media/media/store/10475.) and the usual 6.35mm phono jack on the other end. That's one difference between a $25 (or $2) ear bud set and a $1500 studio headphone.

Answer (score 1):

There is the total thickness of the wire. Overall thickness of all the strands combined. And then there is the choice of whether to use more and thinner strands or use fewer and thicker strands.

The total thickness is chosen to be small because there is not much power conducted to the earphones (compared to a loudspeaker), and consumers like thin wires. The choice to use more and finer strands actually makes the wire more flexible and less likely to break.

Answer (score 0):

If they were thicker, they'd be heavier. This pulls on the earbuds and would increase the chance of them falling out of your ears. Try taping 1m of speaker cable to each earbud and see what it feels like.

Headphone wires tend to break at the ends, where the flexible wire meets the solid body. For over-ear headphones, you can get ones that have a plug and socket rather than just a wire going into plastic, enabling you to replace the wire if it gets damaged.